# Finding complete general solution of differential equation with repeated roots (undetermined coefficents)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

How do you get a complete general solution for a differential like this?

$y^{\prime\prime}+6y^{\prime}+9y=14e^{-3x}$

This is what I have so far for the first part of the problem: $yp=Ce^{-3x}, yp'=-3Ce^{-3x}, yp'' = 9Ce^{-3x}$ and I plug these into:

$ (9Ce^{-3x})+6*-3Ce^{-3x}+9Ce^{-3x}$ for solving for C which gives C=0  which doesnt seem correct at all.  Have I made a mistake or is there something I am missing here?

Comment: You have to first solve the associated homogeneous ED $y''+6y'+9y=0$

Comment: If you want to understand the theory for solving this equation, I recommend this lecture from ever amiable Arthur Mattuck at MIT: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03-differential-equations-spring-2010/video-lectures/lecture-13-finding-particular-sto-inhomogeneous-odes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation can be written in terms of $D=\frac{d}{dx}$ as
$$
                (D+3)^{2}y =14e^{-3x}
$$
The annihilator of $e^{-3x}$ is (D+3). Therefore,
$$
                     (D+3)^{3}y = 0.
$$
The general solution is
$$
  y = Ae^{-3x}+Bxe^{-3x}+Cx^{2}e^{-3x}
$$
Plugging back into the original equation, and using $(D+3)^{2}(e^{-3x}f)=e^{-3x}D^{2}f$
$$
           (D+3)^{2}(Ae^{-3x}+Bxe^{-3x}+Cx^{2}e^{-3x})=14e^{-3x}\\
             C(D+3)^{2}(x^{2}e^{-3x}) = 14e^{-3x} \\
               Ce^{-3x}D^{2}x^{2} = 14e^{-3x} \\
                   2Ce^{-3x} = 14e^{-3x} \\
                     C = 7.
$$
So the general solution involves two arbitrary constants $A$ and $B$, and is given by
$$
                   y(x) = Ae^{-3x}+Bxe^{-3x}+7x^{2}e^{-3x}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Rather, you should find that $$y_p''+6y_p'+9y_p=9Ce^{-3x}-18Ce^{-3x}+9Ce^{-3x}=(9-18+9)Ce^{-3x}=0\cdot Ce^{-3x}=0,$$ and so *any* choice of constant $C$ will give you a solution to the homogeneous differential equation $$y''+6y'+9y=0.\tag{$\star$}$$

In other words, $Ce^{-3x}$ is a solution to $(\star),$ *not* a particular solution to the ODE $$y''+6y'+9y=14e^{-3x}.$$ Moreover, $Ce^{-3x}$ is not the general solution to $(\star),$ because the characteristic equation has a repeated root. Instead, your general (and particular) solution should be some polynomial *multiplied by* $e^{-3x}.$